# Explicit type annotation vs "as" keyword

Tags: typescript

```
const names: string[] = [];
const names = [] as string[];
```

In TypeScript, is there a semantic difference between the above two statements? If so, when would we prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simple as:

- Use type annotation if you want a new variable to be of that type.
- Use type assertion (`as` keyword) if you want to tell the compiler that some
  expression has some specific type (even if it doesn't really).